# en-dash with half-sized space on either the left or the right

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, punctuation

I am looking to produce directional variants of the en-dash. A "left en-dash" should have half of ordinary inter-word spacing on its right and allow line-breaks only on its left; a "right en-dash" should have half of ordinary inter-word spacing on its left and allow line-breaks only on its right. This is intended to aid the visual parsing of parenthetical phrases: "Here - as in his other works - the composer alludes to Italian folk dances."

**What is the best way to define such commands?** Let's name them `\ldash` and `\rdash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\newcommand{\ldash}{--\nobreak\,\nobreak\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\rdash}{\unskip\nobreak\,\nobreak--}
```

`\nobreak` inserts a large `\penalty`, discouraging (not avoiding) a line or page break at that location. A small space on the sides are offered by `\,`, while `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces` removes the whitespace naturally inserted between words.

Comment: Usage for your solution would be `some words \ldash parenthetical expression \rdash{} some words`. Is there an easy way to modify the `\rdash` macro so that I can omit `{}` after it?

Comment: @user14996: [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) can be used: `\usepackage{xspace}\newcommand{\rdash}{\unskip\nobreak\,\nobreak--\xspace}`

Comment: Isn't `\nolinebreak` instead of `\nobreak` cleaner here?

Comment: Actually, a better approach might be to prepend `\leavevmode` to `\rdash`: `\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\,\nobreak--\xspace`; otherwise the first `\nobreak` will be equivalent to a `\nopagebreak` if `\rdash` is used paragraph-initially, right? It does make sense for `\rdash` to  have no spacing if used paragraph-initially (for whatever reason; of course this shouldn't normally occur), but I'm not sure how to get this effect. This case won't occur in normal code, but I think it might occur accidentally, so perhaps one should guard against it?

Comment: If `\ldash` happens to be typeset at the beginning of a line, it might strut into the margin. Writing `\hspace*{0pt}\ldash` fixes this.

Comment: Feel free to disagree or work the above comments into the answer, as appropriate :-)